# Testing nhibernate Castle Windsor mappings in httpModules is not registered

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, mstest

I want to write test that verifies mappings in castle windsor.
I am using ASP MVC2 where i am using castle windsor to map my repositories.

I have read this article:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2008/06/04/the-first-spec-you-should-write-when-using-castle.aspx

and based on this i have created my MS Test

```
 [TestMethod()]
        public void GetContainerTest()
        {
            MooseMvc.Infrastructure.DependencyInjectionInitialiser target = new MooseMvc.Infrastructure.DependencyInjectionInitialiser(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            IWindsorContainer container = target.GetContainer();
            foreach (IHandler assignableHandler in container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object)))
            {             
                container.Resolve(assignableHandler.ComponentModel.Service);
            }
        }
```

The data for target.getcontainer() implements

```
 this._windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<TInterfaceType>()
                .ImplementedBy(typeof(TConcreteType)).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

**I get message as follows:**

```
 Looks like you forgot to register the http module 
Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule Add '<add
name="PerRequestLifestyle"
type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule,
Castle.Windsor" />' to the <httpModules> section on your web.config.
If you're running IIS7 in Integrated Mode you will need to  add it to
<modules> section under <system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found beautifull guide

http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-three-a-testing-your-first-installer.ashx

there is not much else to add..

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem and  I have found a solution: You can define an event in the contructor of the unit test to override the LifestyleType.

```
void Kernel_ComponentModelCreated(Castle.Core.ComponentModel model)
{
    if (model.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.Undefined)
        model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Transient;

    if (model.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.PerWebRequest)
        model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Transient;
}

public UnitTest1()
{
    containerWithControllers = new WindsorContainer();

    containerWithControllers.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated += new ComponentModelDelegate(Kernel_ComponentModelCreated);  
}
```

Comment: Haha, a few months later I come to this same issue in another project and it solves it for me again. Thanks! PS Just remember to do this ComponentModelCreated event registration before any Installer or Register calls!